# PHP Sort associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an associative array like this one:

```
$teams_name_points = array();

$name1 = "name1";
$name2 = "name2";
$teams_name_points[$name1] = 1;
$teams_name_points[$name2] = 2;
```

I want to sort this array by the key values, currently it's sorted alphabetically by the key.

I tried to implement my own sorting function, but I do not quite understand how it works.

```
usort($teams_name_points, 'cmp');

function cmp(array $a, array $b){
    if ($a['foo'] < $b['foo']) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($a['foo'] > $b['foo']) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How do I make the compare method work with my array?

Comment: `ksort()` Does that do the trick for you? Also please show what output you get and what your goal is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `asort()` to sort your array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element order is significant.

Comment: That sorts it by value not by key

Comment: @Rizier123 op says "I want to sort this array by the **key values**, currently it's sorted alphabetically **by the key**."- So i assume a "Sort-by-value-and-maintain-keys" is what he is looking for, if "sort-by-key" is the current situtation which he did not want.

Comment: i have understood too so... @Marcus : read docs, if you can read php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: And tbh: Sorting a "Key/Value"-Array, where the key is a player's name, and the value is the score fits to `asort`. Build, sort, iterate -> ranking.

Answer (score 1):

```
$teams_name_points = array();

$name1 = "name1";
$name2 = "name2";
$teams_name_points[$name1] = 2;
$teams_name_points[$name2] = 1;
print_r($teams_name_points);
asort($teams_name_points); // sort by value low to high
print_r($teams_name_points);
arsort($teams_name_points); // sort by value high to low
print_r($teams_name_points);
```

Comment: Also correct answer, but I can only accept one so you sir have my upvote

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough, [as per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), you'll only want to accept the **values** of the arrays as the arguments to cmp().

E.g.

```
cmp($earlier_array_value, $later_array_value){
    ...
}
```

Also, of course, be aware that `usort()` is only warranted when you're running a comparison that is custom and not-numerically-straightforward.  Simple comparisons by `>` or `<` can be more easily done with [existing native sort functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).